# Not able to see the data in componentWillMount()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-csv

I am doing the `.get()` request in Jquery and updated the state as well.

**My question is:**

Why am I not able to see the data in `console.log(this.state.storage)` in `componentWillMount()` as well as `componentDidMount()` but I do get the output in `render()`?

Also I will need to do operations on fetched data, in which lifecycle I should do it?

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    storage: []
  }
}

componentWillMount() {
  $.get('data.csv', (data) => this.setState({
    storage: data
  }));
  console.log(this.state.storage); //No Output
}

componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.state.storage); //No Output
}

render() {
    return ( 
    <div >{this.state.storage}</div> //Do get the Output
    );
```

Comment: what error are you seeing, and what did you do to resolve?

Comment: Please check my update @Soren

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847754/668501

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState` is asynchronous in how it updates the component state; [documentation here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). If you want to see the changes effected by `this.setState` then you have to pass a callback to the function call

Also, you can do your operations in the callback of the `$.get` method as shown below

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    storage: []
  }
}

myCustomOperations = (data) => {
  // do custom operations here with data
}

componentWillMount() {
  $.get('data.csv', (data) => {
    this.myCustomOperation(data);
    this.setState({
      storage: data
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.storage); // correct output
      // this.myCustomOperation(this.state.storage) // if you want to do the custom operation after the data has been put into the state
    });
  });
  console.log(this.state.storage); //No Output
}

componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.state.storage); //No Output
}

render() {
    return ( 
    <div >{this.state.storage}</div> //Do get the Output
    );
```